# Execute stored procedure with a nullable parameter from SQL server management studio

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have a stored procedure, **uspUser_GetUserDetails**, with several parameters. It gets called something like this:

```
uspUser_GetUserDetails 'LastName','FirstName', 'UserId', 'dtDate', 'DistrictId'
```

How do I run the stored procedure if the `dtDate` parameter is null. I tried

```
uspUser_GetUserDetails 'LastName','FirstName','UserId','','DistrictId'
```

but it doesn't do anything. Will something like this work?

```
uspUser_GetUserDetails 'LastName','FirstName','UserId',null,'DistrictId'
```

This takes forever to execute the query without returning any result. Note that the question is not about how to create a SP with a nullable parameter. My SP works fine from C#, it shows sqlvalue {null} in the parameters. I just want to test it quickly from SQL server management studio and know how to pass null parameter to it in this situation.

Comment: How are you executing the said stored procedure?

Comment: We need to see the SP and the indexes you have on your user table

Comment: "This takes forever to execute the query without returning any result.". Yes. Your proc is running with a NULL value but there is now a performance issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the syntax is fine for all the SPs I tried later. And there is no performance issue. The problem with `uspUser_GetUserDetails 'LastName','FirstName','UserId',null,'DistrictId'` before is probably related to "Timeout expired".

Alternatively, `EXEC    [dbo].[uspSPName]
        @LastName = N'LastName'
        @FirstName = N'',
        @UserId = 0,
        @dtDate = NULL,
        @DistrictId = 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcName
    @Parameter1 INT = 1,
    @Parameter2 VARCHAR (100) = 'StringValue',
    @Parameter3 VARCHAR (100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN

END
```

Use Optional parameter, then no need to pass in calling of procedure.

Comment: But sometimes it is more convenient to always pass the parameter (e.g. if it can be null or not null).